# How to set the steptime of simulink compilation dll through the api interface？

Tags: api, dll, simulink

As mentioned in the title, the model steptime needs to be set by calling dll through the API interface. Please tell me how you set the step length in this way. Thank you！

It is expected to set the internal steptime of simulink compilation dll through the API interface call.